# When asking/answering on this site; Is there a way to fix the page in place so that you only see the displayed output as you type?

Tags: discussion

I am a touch typist who uses Mathematics Stack Exchange site mostly and would like to know if there exists a way to type a question/answer on any Stack Exchange site with all the necessary formatting without the page automatically scrolling back up to where you input the math code?

There must be a way to dis-engage this annoying auto-scroll feature so that I can only see the rendered output as I type.

This is the simplest way I can think to word this question; if it is unclear to anyone what I’m asking then please let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: Why don't you use this http://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Z0p.png ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Thanks for your response; it doesn't work however. Or how do I implement it? I use mathematics stack exchange primarily, but I only want to _see_ the output not the input code that I type in.

Comment: Can't you just pull it all the way to bottom and just see what you type ? i.e. the textarea

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like No because it just zips back up automatically to where I type in the code

Comment: You mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uZxYs.png) doesn't work for you ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I guess so, all I see when I click that link is a long list of identical sentences how do I use that in this or any other SE sites? It looks promising however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33140/discussion-between-the-it-guy-you-dont-like-and-blaze).

Comment: downvote for WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Summary of discussion with OP

Just wants to see the preview as he types in the Textarea but it is being obstructed as `OnKeydown` action triggers `Scroll UP` pulling textarea in view

[image]

> Suggestion solutions

- Write your own extension that catches the event handler before it triggers. Good luck **:)**
- Pull the bottom of textarea to the bottom of the screen so that textarea increases
- Pull the bottom of textarea all the up so that all you see is a single line input box

Answer (score 2):

Here is a userscript that I found in StackApps which was created partly by Antonio Vargas that enables side-by-side editing. This userscript adds a button to the editor toolbar ('Toggle Side-By-Side Editing') shown in the blue box in the image below so you can view the preview and markdown side by side when asking or answering a question or when editing an existing question or answer. You can also hide the preview as shown in the orange box.

To get this script first install Greasemonkey if you are using Firefox or Tampermonkey if using Chrome, and then click **[here](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/side-by-side-editing.user.js)**.

[image: Side by side editing]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that has been brought to my attention recently: Use [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/editor) and this allows you to see the rendered output and the text input simultaneously. Furthermore, you can minimize the text input box to such an extent that it barely is visible at all.